# swift 3 compiler segmentation fault 11

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, swift3

i know my question title can be duplicate but cause for the issue is not,
please help as i am not getting anywhere with this. I have already read all other thread solving some optional problem, or print(".") solving the issue.
I used print(".") and it worked but it is doing nothing now! please help me 
see [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUbF5.png) and [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2w1.png) for reference

thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all do not post pictures. Post code. At least you have to call `super.viewWillAppear()`. And **never** use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. You throw away the type information and fight the strong type system. Use Swift native types (`Array` and `Dictionary`)

Comment: thanks for the help @vadian, will i did added `super.viewWillAppear()` but i just added more optionals like `(result as? NSMutableArray)!` instead of `result as! NSMutableArray`, it does the work,  and i will sure act on your advice next time

Comment: It's impossible to cast any type to `NSMutableArray` in Swift. That causes the error. As mentioned in the first comment, use Swift `Array`.